# Qual a melhor maneira de organizar views no Django?

Tags: python, django, view, convenções

Tenho o views.py no meu projeto de estudo aonde nele agrupo desde métodos para representar views (métodos que retornam HttpResponse), até views genéricas baseadas em classe (como DetailView, ListView).

Estava pensando: quais as melhores práticas para se organizar as views referentes à um certo modelo sem espalha-las através de um arquivo inteiro?
Posso agrupa-las de alguma maneira em uma única classe e organizar meu arquivo?

Comment: Dei uma olhada aqui se não havia algum problema em fazer o seguinte: agrupar todos os métodos que retornam HttpResponse referentes ao meu modelo em uma classe e torna-los estáticos. Fiz e deu certo. Existe algum problema em fazer isso do ponto de vista técnico?

Comment: Boa pergunta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estou tentando entender sua pergunta. Se for no tocante a organização você pode
dividir seu views.py em pequenos módulos, caso ele fique muito grande.

views.py original segue abaixo:

```
# (imports)
...

def view1(request):
    pass

def view2(request):
   pass

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template = 'core/index.html'

index = IndexView.as_view()
...
```

Você pode ter essa mesma estrutura de forma mais organizada.
Abaixo segue um exemplo de como modularizar o mesmo views.py.

```
views/
  __init__.py
  base.py
  cbvs.py
```

base.py :

```
# (imports)
...

def view1(request):
    pass

def view2(request):
   pass

...
```

cbvs.py :

```
# (imports)
...

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template = 'core/index.html'

index = IndexView.as_view()

...
```

__init__.py :

```
from base import view1
from base import view2
from cbvs import index
```

Além de que você pode utilizar essa mesma estrutura para organizar outros arquivos grandes no seu projeto Django.

Comment: É bem isso mesmo Arthur. Apenas no quesito organização, afinal tudo está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Arthur hoje percebi que realmente a melhor maneira de organizar minhas views é como você disse acima. Estava fazendo classes com outras classes internas, mas devido a alguns problemas como acessar valores da classe mais externa, vi que sua solução seria a mais interessante. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.